# Fetching the title of a website

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I browsed through SO, but what I found were examples "how to manipulate a piece of html".
But in my case, I want to fetch a HTML file by a given URL and just parse the websites title not the whole file.

Is there any way to do this with jQuery or any jQuery like framework?

regards,

Comment: How are you trying to fetch the html file?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The only way is to use a server side proxy which makes the web request and parses out the title which you can return to your page.

See a php example [here](http://www.abdulqabiz.com/blog/archives/2007/05/31/php-proxy-script-for-cross-domain-requests/)

For python try the [urllib](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib.html)

Comment: Right +1. Being able to do this with the browser only would open the door to many security issues.

Comment: Any Python / AppEngine example out there? =)

Answer (score -1):

[2911930](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2911930/jquery-cant-load-the-head-title-in-chrome/2913159#2913159) looks to have the answer

```
$.get("yoururl", function(response){
    var theTitle = (/<title>(.*?)<\/title>/m).exec(response)[1];
    alert(theTitle);
});
```

**edit** As pointed out by the commenters, you'll be restricted by [SOP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) to pages only within your domain. And, generally, parsing HTML with regular expressions is a [*Bad Thing*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454), but not too bad in this case.

Comment: This will not work unless the url is on the same domain as the calling page

Comment: You're supposing OP only requests urls from his own domain.  This won't work as soon as a foreign domain comes into play. Furthermore, parsing html with regular expressions is a bad idea in general.